# Django cache how to remove key prefix of ":1:"

Tags: django

I set a cache in Django as below:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
...
cache.set("cae9ad31b9206a1b5594813b509e1003", "test", timeout=10)
```

It generates a key like this:

```
:1:cae9ad31b9206a1b5594813b509e1003
```

How to remove `:1:` prefix from the key?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't have to worry about it, really, as this doesn't affect how you `get` the value of a key.

```
cache.get("cae9ad31b9206a1b5594813b509e1003")
# outputs
"test"
```

---

**Why's this happening?**

Django generates the cache keys by combining the `key` you give it with the `version` of the cache.

Example:

```
cache.set("my_key", "value", version=2)
# becomes
":2:my-key"
```

Since, by default `version=1`, that is why in your case it becomes `:1:cae9a...`.

This is called [Cache Versioning](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/cache/#cache-versioning). It is useful because this way you can have multiple cached versions of a particular object.

---

**How to override this?**

If you still want to override this behaviour for whatever reason, you can do it as the [docs suggest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/cache/#cache-key-transformation).

First create a function somewhere like this:

```
def my_key_maker(key, key_prefix, version):
    return key # just return the key without doing anything
```

Then, in your `CACHES` settings do this:

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": ...,
        # other settings ...
        "KEY_FUNCTION": "path.to.my_key_maker"
    }
}
```

Comment: i override a function, and set `KYE_FUNCTION` in settings.py, then redis cannot get anything
i override this in `__init__.py` named `make_key`
`'KEY_FUNCTION': 'package.make_key'`
is it correct?

Comment: @crankwan I had made a mistake in my answer, I'm sorry about that. The `KEY_FUNCTION` settings should be inside the `CACHES` settings. I've updated my code.

Comment: i make it this
`
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': 'localhost:6379',
        'KYE_FUNCTION': 'package.make_key'
    },
}
`
it didn't work

Comment: I think you've a typo there. It should be `KEY_FUNCTION`, whereas you've `KYE_FUNCTION` (notice the `KEY` and `KYE` difference?).

Comment: @crankwan Okay, maybe you've got the path wrong. Where is the `__init__.py` file? Is it in the same folder as your settings file? Or in the outer folder?

Comment: @crankwan I just tested this and it's working for me without any trouble. Are you getting any errors or anything? Also, if you're using the django shell, please restart it after you've changed the settings.

Comment: no errors alert, i use `print(cache.set("cae9ad31b9206a1b5594813b509e1003", "test", timeout=30))`, it outputs `True`. I check it in redis-cli with `keys *`, but nothing returns.

Comment: @crankwan In redis-cli, type this command: `INFO keyspace`. What''s the output?

Comment: thank you very much, i know what makes it incorrect, i tried `django-redis-cache` before but i dont change it back to the config for `django-redis`, sorry, it took you much time to my question. thank you! :)

Comment: @crankwan Ah, don't worry, it's okay.

Comment: im new to django, i will disturb you later if have some question.  : )