# Memcached service is working as expected but stats items is empty

Tags: python, django, docker, memcached

I'm using Django with docker - In my **Docker-compose** I created a memcached service:

```yaml
 memcached:
   build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: memcached.Dockerfile
   ports:
     - '11211:11211'
   expose:
     - "11211"
```

the **Dockerfile** looks like this:

```sh
FROM  Memcached: latest
USER root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        telnet \
        telnetd \
        libmemcached-tools \
        netcat
USER memcache

EXPOSE 11211
```

Now the cache location is defined in settings.py  which retrieves it from .ENV file :

**settings.py**

```py
if os.getenv("CACHE_BACKEND"):
    cache_timeout = os.getenv("CACHE_TIMEOUT")
    CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': os.getenv("CACHE_BACKEND"),
            'LOCATION': os.getenv("CACHE_LOCATION"),
            'TIMEOUT': None
        }
    }
```

**.env**

```py
CACHE_BACKEND = django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache

CACHE_LOCATION =  ***********:11211 # I covered the container name 

CACHE_TIMEOUT = None
```

the actual caching function is wrapped and uses as an annotation:

```py
def caching(code_version=None):
    """
    Decorator with argument
    :param code_version: code version from DB
    :return: real_decorator
    """
    def real_decorator(func):
        """
        Wrapper function that reads from the cache if the value already exists and if not then it
        saves it to the cache
        :param func: wrapped function
        :return: Wrapper function
        """

        def func_wrapper(request):
            from django.http import HttpResponse
            from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
            from django.core.cache import cache

            if code_version:
                cache.version = code_version
            url = request.get_full_path()
            url_hash = f"{abs(hash(url))}"
            save_cache: bool = len(url_hash) <= 250
            print(f"SAVE CACHE-----------------------{save_cache}")
            if save_cache:
                try:
                    cache_result = cache.get(url_hash)
                    if cache_result:
                        print(f"\n\n\nHello my name is {url} ,& I'm A memcached user")
                        return HttpResponse(cache_result)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
            data = json.dumps(func(request), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
            if save_cache:
                print(f"\n\n\nHello my name is {url} ,& I'm A memcached pusher------------------------{url_hash}-----------{cache}--------")
                try:
                    cache.set(url_hash, data)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
            return HttpResponse(data)

        return func_wrapper

    return real_decorator
```

now the code is working well, and it appears that the memcached is working fine.
I also printed logs in the caching function that shows me that the system gets its data from the cache. **but** when I'm trying to use the

```sh
memcdump --servers=localhost
```

I get an  END answer.
when I'm stats over the container the

```
STAT curr_items 0
STAT total_items 0
```

I'm in real tunnel vision about it and will be happy for every suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to use memcached with django .

I have a similar issue , and i'm using a local memcached server through unix socket .

In my python program  I inserted a test like this :

```
data_cache = caches['mymemcached']

data_cache.set(key='test_key', value=datetime.datetime.now().isoformat())
```

and if i run

```
memcdump --server=/var/run/memcached/memcached.sock | grep test
```

from a shell I got nothing .

I'm pulling my hair off

EDIT :
I found something interesting in this post :
[Django cache how to remove key prefix of ":1:"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47713718/django-cache-how-to-remove-key-prefix-of-1)